# Remove stopwords list from list in Python (Natural Language Processing)

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I have been trying to remove stopwords using python 3 code but my code does not seem to work,I want to know how to remove stop words from the below list.  The example structure is as below:

```
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords

    word_split1=[['amazon','brand','- 
    ','solimo','premium','almonds',',','250g','by','solimo'],
    ['hersheys','cocoa', 'powder', ',', '225g', 'by', 'hersheys'], 
    ['jbl','t450bt','extra','bass','wireless','on- 
    ear','headphones','with','mic','white','by','jbl','and']]
```

I am trying to remove stop words and tried the below is my code and i would appreciate if anyone can help me rectify the issue.. here is the code below

```
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

    filtered_words=[]
    for i in word_split1:
        if i not in stop_words:
            filtered_words.append(i)
```

I get error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<ipython-input-451-747407cf6734>", line 3, in <module>
    if i not in stop_words:
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of lists.

Try:

```
word_split1=[['amazon','brand','- ','solimo','premium','almonds',',','250g','by','solimo'],['hersheys','cocoa', 'powder', ',', '225g', 'by', 'hersheys'],['jbl','t450bt','extra','bass','wireless','on-ear','headphones','with','mic','white','by','jbl','and']]
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_words=[]
for i in word_split1:
    for j in i:
        if j not in stop_words:
            filtered_words.append(j)
```

---

or flatten your list.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain    

word_split1=[['amazon','brand','- ','solimo','premium','almonds',',','250g','by','solimo'],['hersheys','cocoa', 'powder', ',', '225g', 'by', 'hersheys'],['jbl','t450bt','extra','bass','wireless','on-ear','headphones','with','mic','white','by','jbl','and']]
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_words=[]
for i in chain.from_iterable(word_split1):
    if i not in stop_words:
        filtered_words.append(i)
```

or

```
filtered_words = [i for i in chain.from_iterable(word_split1) if i not in stop_words]
```

Comment: Hello Rakesh Thanks for support/contrubution to my question and i got the exact output from the below code  
`stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))    

clean_models = []
for m in word_split1:
    stop_m = [i for i in m if str(i).lower() not in stopset]
    clean_models.append(stop_m)
`

Answer (score 1):

The list is a 2D array and you're trying to hash a list, convert it to a 1D array first, then your code would work fine,

```
word_split1 = [j for x in word_split1 for j in x] 

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

filtered_words=[]
for i in word_split1:
    if i not in stop_words:
        filtered_words.append(i)
```

Comment: Thanks @Specbug for your support